# Cannot access array objects when that array is itself an attribute of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, attributes

I am unable to access an array of objects that is itself an attribute of a larger object.

```
console.log(skillprofiles);
console.log(skillprofiles.skills);
```

The above statements return an array of two objects that each have an attribute that is a, seemingly, valid array of objects ("skills" in this example).

I am unable to access the "skills" array attribute. The data I am ultimately trying to get at is the "item_name" attribute.  As far as I know, that should be accessible via:

```
skillprofiles[0].skills[0].item_name
```

Interestingly enough, verifying the type of the "skills" attribute with "typeof" returns "object" instead of array.  This could be because I am transferring an array of objects from one object to another earlier in my code. I thought I was doing this properly and seemed to have confirmed that by my logging statements.

UPDATE with actual data:

```
[{
"skillprofile_id": 144,
"skillprofile_name": " On-boarding",
"start_date": "January 30 2012",
"progress": 0,
"complete_date": " ",
"category": 1053,
"skills": [{
    "category": "Acquire: Onboard New Hires",
    "item_name": "3. On-boarding a New Hire - Day 1",
    "skill_type": "activity",
    "object_id": 68,
    "duration": "8:00:00",
    "sco_status_code": 6,
    "action": "activity",
    "has_forums": false
}, {
    "category": "Acquire: Onboard New Hires",
    "item_name": "4. On-boarding Checklist",
    "skill_type": "activity",
    "object_id": 67,
    "duration": "1:00:00",
    "sco_status_code": 6,
    "action": "activity",
    "has_forums": false
}]
}, {
"skillprofile_id": 143,
"skillprofile_name": " Setting Up Systems",
"start_date": "January 30 2012",
"progress": 0,
"complete_date": " ",
"category": 1053,
"skills": [{
    "category": "Acquire: Onboard New Hires",
    "item_name": "1. Office Organization",
    "skill_type": "activity",
    "object_id": 65,
    "duration": "4:00:00",
    "sco_status_code": 6,
    "action": "activity",
    "has_forums": false
}, {
    "category": "Acquire: Onboard New Hires",
    "item_name": "2. Welcome to the Team Documents",
    "skill_type": "activity",
    "object_id": 66,
    "duration": "2:00:00",
    "sco_status_code": 6,
    "action": "activity",
    "has_forums": false
}, {
    "category": "Acquire: Onboard New Hires",
    "item_name": "3. Welcome Documents: Feedback ",
    "skill_type": "activity",
    "object_id": 150,
    "duration": "1:00:00",
    "sco_status_code": 6,
    "action": "activity",
    "has_forums": false
}]
}]
```

UPDATE 2:

Given the responses so far, it seems that I should be able to run the following:

```
$.each(skillprofiles, function(){
  console.log(this.skills)
});
```

I can do this from the console, but the console statements come back as "undefined" when run from my code

Comment: Did you tried skillprofiles.skills[0].item_name or skillprofiles.skills.item_name ?

Comment: I think you'll either have to show us the real/working code or you'll have to include the code where you build the `skillprofiles` and `skills` objects.  As it stands now, we have no information about what's really in those objects.  FYI: `typeof [1,2,3] == "object"` - that is normal for arrays.

Comment: You need to post what the data actually looks like. From what you've posted here it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 1):

In your first block of code, skills is directly a child of skillprofiles. Whereas in the second one, you write skillprofiles[o].skills. If the first one works, maybe your code should be:

```
skillprofiles.skills[0].item_name
```

Answer (score 0):

With that data structure, the proper access would be:

```
skillprofiles[i].skills[j].item_name
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wPLZZ/

---

`skillprofiles` is an array of objects so you get an object from the array with:

```
skillprofiles[i]
```

Each object in that array, has a number of properties and one of those properties is named `skills` so you would get that property with

```
skillprofiles[i].skills
```

The contents of the `skills` property is another array so you would get an item from that aray with this:

```
skillprofiles[i].skills[j]
```

That array holds objects with their own properties so you would access a specific property with this:

```
skillprofiles[i].skills[j].item_name
```